# Cannot implicitly convert type void to int - how to solve?

Tags: c#

I am still new to C# and trying to resolve this issue here. I have a method with an `int` return type, and when I add error message, I get an error and the code doesn't compile.

```
private static int GetNum(CAP cap)
{
    List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();

    var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];

    if (unitNumber == null)
    {
        // this line of code causes the error
        return errors.Add(new Error("Unit not found"));
    }
    else
    {
        return int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress);
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I can do to resolve this.

Comment: `List<T>` doesn't return anything. So you cannot use it in a `return`-statement. I'm not sure why you have a list in the first place, when all you're doing is adding a **single** element to it. Anyway in order to return multiple things from a single function, you need to use the [`out`-keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier).

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.add?view=net-6.0): `errors.Add` doesn't return anything (it's `void`). What would you expect a numeric result to be from calling `.Add`? Should it just pick a random number between -2147483648 and 2147483647?

Comment: Consider throwing an exception instead of returning an `Error`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` returns nothing (i.e. `void`), it can't be transformed into `int`. If you want to return some kind of [`Either`](https://livebook.manning.com/concept/functional-programming/either) type you can return a [value tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples):

```
    private static (int? Value, List<Error>? Errors) GetNum(CAP cap)
    {
        var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];
        if (unitNumber == null)
        {
            List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();
            errors.Add(new Error("Unit not found"));
            return (null, errors);
        }
        else
        {
            return (int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress), null);
        }

    }
```

And then check the return:

```cs
var (val, errors) = GetNum(...);
if(val.HasValue)
{
    .... // Use value
}
else
{
   // Do something with errors
}
```

Comment: how do I call this method then in another method? GetNum((x),null)? then it says No overload for method 'GetNum' takes 2 arguments error

Comment: @Andrew number of parameters the methods accepts has not changed, only return type, so you should call it as you did before passing instance of `CAP` and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you throw an exception instead of returning an `Error`.

```
private static int GetNum(CAP cap)
{
    var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];
    if (unitNumber == null)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Unit not found");
    }

    return int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress);
}
```

You might additionally, change the function name to `GetUnitNumber`. Then I'd think about why `CAP` instances exist with missing values for `"UnitNumbers"` in the `pointsAddress` collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your error arises because you specify the return type of your method as `int` and you are trying to return the return value of the method `Add` inside the if clause. `Add`s return type is void, so it does not return anything, which is in conflict to the expected `int`.

It seems to me that a "TryDoSomeThing" pattern is what you are trying to implement.
In this case you should return a `bool` to signal whether the procedure has succeeded, and return the real value or the error messages via `out`.

```
private static bool TryGetNum(CAP cap, out int num, out List<Error> errors)
{
    int num = -1; // choose a default value here
    List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();
    var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];
    if (unitNumber == null)
    {
        errors.Add(new Error("Unit not found")); // add your error messages
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        num = int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress); // this will be accessible from the out parameter
        return 
    }

}
```

Using it similarly like the `TryParse` methods you could call it like this:

```
bool result = TryGetNum(cap, out int num, out List<Error> errors);
if(result)
{
    // use num here
}
else
{
    // use errors here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simple Words a `void` Method is a Method that does a Action without returning a value, therefore when you ask it for a value such as `int` it gives you a parsing exception, i'd suggest doing something like this:

```
private static int GetNum(CAP cap)
    {
        List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();
        var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];
        if (unitNumber == null)
        {
           var error = new Error("Unit not found");
           errors.Add(error);
           //Creating the Error and puting in the list is just writen here right now because i was not sure if you in some way need that to happen, in other words you can remove it if you don't need it
           throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Unit not found");
        }
        else
        {
            return int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `Add()` returns void. When using the output of `Add()` as the return value for your method, you are trying to output a `void` value in an `int` method.

A quick solution for this would be to make the method nullable and then returning a null int, like this:

```
private static int? GetNum(CAP cap) // Notice the ? after the type, this means it can also be null
{
    List<Error> errors = new List<Error>();
    var unitNumber = cap.pointsAddress["UnitNumbers"];
    if (unitNumber == null)
    {
        errors.Add(new Error("Unit not found")); // this create the error
        return null;
  }
  else
    {
        return int.Parse(unitNumber.AccessAddress);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your expectation :

- return error message when there is null/empty
- return int

root cause : return type must match method signature declaration.

suggestion : you probably violating Single Responsibilty principal. your method should only do 1 thing, return the value of CAP object. let the caller handle exceptional case.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem, and it is hard to suggest which one is best depends on the usage context.

1. Throw exception. can treat null, empty as exceptional case. The call will need to catch the method and act accordingly.
2. return multiple values, which can archive by declare custom type(class or struct) or valueTuples(int,string). which I think is not really fit what you are trying to do.
3. try pattern. you can refer to it from .net own class library.(eg. Int.TryParse) . the caller need to check for a bool and act accordingly.
4. change return type from int to int? . caller will need to check for null and display message accordingly.